# Access Build Config from parent project in Android

Tags: java, android, android-manifest, buildconfig

I got an Android Studio project with some subprojects. From one subproject I need to access the Build Config of the parent project for checking if a new verison is available at the Google Play Store (comparing the local version number with the one at the play store). Within a project I can do it with:

```
BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME
```

But how can I get the version of the parent project?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found it out by myselfe:

I'm using

```
intent.putExtra("VERSION", BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME);
```

on the parent activity and

```
getIntent().getExtras().getString("VERSION")
```

on the childactivity